# Beginner Needing Java Programming Help! I can't figure out how to go about solving this

Tags: java, loops

I am a beginner to Programming in Java and I cannot figure out how to solve this problem:

"Create an Investment application that calculates how many years it will take for a $2,500 investment to be worth at least $5,000 if compounded annually at 7.5%"

I have tried using a for loop and  a do-while loop to try solving the problem but it doesn't work.  Please Help!

This is what I have after trying everything so far:

```
/*Investment.java
 *This program determines how many years it would take for $2500 to turn into $5000 if 
 *compounded at 7.5% annually.
 *Date: October 27th, 2012
 */

/**
 * The following application calculates how many years it will take for $2500 to
 * turn into $5000 if compounded at 7.5% annually.
 */

public class Investment {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int MAX_AMOUNT = 5000;
        int investment = 2500;
        double interest = 0.075;
        double totalValue;

        do {
            totalValue = (investment + (investment * interest));
        } while (totalValue < MAX_AMOUNT);
        System.out.println(totalValue); 
    }   
}
```

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: You're just setting the `totalValue` value inside the `do-while` loop with the same result, when you should update it on every loop.

Comment: As well as the bug mentioned above, the body of your loop is going to print the `totalValue` i.e. some number > $5000, rather than *the number of goes through the loop it took to get there*.

Comment: I would avoid using do-while loops and just stick to while loops. Any do-while can be written as a while loop. While loops are easier to read.

Comment: I think the question is asking to calculate the number of years. Your code doesn't seem to care about that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're just computing the value `investment + investment*interest` over and over again, and storing it in totalValue. Instead, you need to be accumulating. It could look like:

```
totalValue = investment;
do {
    totalValue = (totalValue + totalValue*interest);
}
while (totalValue < MAX_VALUE);
```

This way, you keep actually adding the interest and accumulating it.

Additionally, as was commented, you're looking for the number of times that the loop looped, rather than just the value at the end. So you need to count the number of times that the loop is repeated by incrementing a counter each time.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a single line, using basic math.

the time (n) to have a value (V) in the futue if initial amount (A) at interest rate (i) compuonded c times per year : n = [ln(V) - ln(A)] / [ ln(c+i) - ln(c)]

```
double getYearsToMature(double v, double i, int c, double a)
{
   return (Math.log(v) - Math.log(a))/(Math.log(c+i) - Math.log(c));
}
```

since it says in the problem "at least $5000" just round it up and cast to int..

```
int answer = (Integer) Math.round(getYearsToMature(...));
```

also you will get some compiler warnings about loss of precision for casting from long to Integer - use float instead of double, or ignore warnings if your numbers are small

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to solve this in a simpler manner by searching for appropriate formulas for calculating this (instead of using a loop). While programming, it's not only important to understand and use language constructs (like loops and conditions) properly, but also to learn the best "algorithm" to do it in an optimal way.

From http://www.csgnetwork.com/directcalccompinttrainer.html (one of the links found through a search):
The time period (n) to have FV in the future if the initial investment A at i interest compounded c times per year:

```
    ln(FV) - ln(A)
n = ------------------
    ln(c + i) - ln(c)
```

NOTE: ln is the natural logarithm function.

For annually compounded interest, the formula becomes:

```
    ln(FV) - ln(A)
n = ------------------
    ln(1 + i) - ln(1)
```

Here's the code using this formula (it'll give you the exact number of years, including a fraction, which you can adjust/truncate and print):

```java
import java.lang.Math;

public class Investment {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int MAX_AMOUNT = 5000;
        int investment = 2500;
        double interest = 0.075;
        double years;

        years = (log(MAX_AMOUNT) - log(investment)) / (log(1 + interest) - log(1))
        System.out.println(years); 
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
double years = 0;
while(interest < totalvalue) {
    totalValue = investment*interest;
    years++;
}
```

?

Answer (score 0):

To do it iteratively, note that you need to compute the number of *years*, not the investment amount. Your loop is not adding to the total value, it's recomputing it as if it were the first year each time through the loop. This would work instead:

```
public class Investment {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int MAX_AMOUNT = 5000;
        int investment = 2500;
        double interest = 0.075;
        double totalValue;

        int years = 0;
        do {
            totalValue += totalValue * interest;
            years++;
        } while (totalValue < MAX_AMOUNT);
        System.out.println(years);
    }
}
```

However, a better approach is to look at the formula for total value after N years at I percent per annum return, compounded annually:

> currentValue = initialInvestment * (1 + I)<sup>N</sup>

Then you can solve for N, plug in 2500 for `initialInvestment` and 7500 for `currentValue`. This will generally give you a fractional value for N, which you then need to round up to get to the number of years needed to reach or exceed the target amount. You'll find the [`Math.log()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log%28double%29) (or [`Math.log10()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log10%28double%29)) function useful for this.